# Sketching a lemniscate curve with a max function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

If I am told to sketch the following  [Lemniscate curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIsDh.png):

$$  r^2 = \max\{a^2 \cos(2\theta),0\}$$

How am I supposed to take into account the max function? Can I simply ignore it and graph

$$  r^2 = a^2\cos(2\theta)?$$

Comment: at $\theta=0, r $ is maximum. When does the RHS go negative?

Comment: It depends on how your graphing tool deals with cases of $\theta$ that has no solution for $r$ (like when $\theta=π/2$, where the equation reads $r^2=-a^2$). If it just ignores them, fine, you can skip the max. If it gives an error and quits, you need the max. If it tries to plot complex values, you need the max. If you're graphing by hand, you may as well keep it, but figure out which $\theta$ gives $0$ and think of it like a piecewise thing instead, like this: $$r^2=\cases{a^2\cos(2\theta)& if $\theta$ is ...\\ 0& otherwise}$$